# How to position correctly with absolute and relative positioning

Tags: html, css, layout, position

I'm working on a webpage that includes a few sections of content, an image slideshow, and a top fixed nav bar. My problem has to do with the layout of the slideshow. I have the slideshow set up to use absolute positioning, but it then sits on top of my other content.

The only way I've been able to get the rest of my content to move lower on the page is to use absolute positioning with everything. If I try to use containers and use relative positioning, it moves my right/left selector arrows and clutters up the whole slideshow.

Can anyone show me a better way to orient content this way along the page?

```css
#doc {
  margin: 40px 0;
}
#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1140px;
}
#container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin-top: 110px;
}
#leftHolder {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin-left: 65px;
}
#rightHolder {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.left {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0px;
}
.right {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  right: 0px;
}
#img {
  height: 600px;
  width: 1140px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="doc">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="container">
      <img src="Images/Slideshow/img1.jpg" id="img" />
      <div id="leftHolder">
        <img onClick="slide(-1)" class="left" src="Images/arrowLeft.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="rightHolder">
        <img onClick="slide(+1)" class="left" src="Images/arrowRight.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute positioned elements are out of the flow. Sure you can't use a relative positioned element?

Comment: Check my answer, you have a lot of mistakes. Hope that helps.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost correct, but only a few things you need to change.

1. Change the `width` properties of the `#rightHolder` and `#leftHolder`.
2. Remove the `margin`s.
3. Give `position: relative` to parent.
4. Negative `margin-top` for both the holders to half of their `height`s.
5. Static `position`ing of the main image.

And lot more changes to document. The below snippet works fine. Kindly check and let me know if you need more help.

```css
#doc {
  margin: 40px 0;
  position: relative;
}
#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#container {
  max-width: 1140px;
}
#leftHolder {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 50%;
}
#rightHolder {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
.left, .right {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
#img {
  height: 600px;
  width: 1140px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="doc">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="container">
      <img src="Images/Slideshow/img1.jpg" id="img" />
      <div id="leftHolder">
        <img onClick="slide(-1)" class="left" src="Images/arrowLeft.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="rightHolder">
        <img onClick="slide(+1)" class="left" src="Images/arrowRight.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ParthChavda Thanks buddy. I wish I could document all the changes I did, but well, for devs, documentation is the worst part. LoL.